# How to get filenames with last modified dates from a network drive using Python?

Tags: python, network-programming

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path


startDir = os.getcwd()

pt = r"K:\Folder"

asm_pths = [pth for pth in Path(pt).iterdir()
            if pth.suffix == '.jpg']


for file in asm_pths:
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(file)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pt):
        for filename in files:
            print(str(filename) + "," + str(time.ctime(mtime)))
```

I am using the above code to extract filenames with last modified dates from a network drive. Code executes with no errors, but the output has the same 'last modified date' for all the files which is not the case when you check the folder. I tried using the code on a local directory and it gives me desired output.
There is one more issue the compiler keeps executing the code. 
So far I have tried sys.exit(), exit(), os.__exit(0). Very confused. Please help.

I am using Komodo Edit and python 3.8.

Comment: you use `os.stat` only once and get values only for one file - and you use the same values all time. You have to use  `os.stat` inside `for` loop with `filename` or rather with  `os.path.join( root, filename )` to have full path to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `os.walk()` you have to use `os.stat()` inside `for`-loop with different `filename` or rather `os.path.join( root, filename )`

```
import os
import time

pt = r"K:\Folder"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pt):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(fullpath)
            print(str(filename) + "," + str(time.ctime(mtime)))
```

Or without `os.walk()`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import time

pt = r"K:\Folder"

asm_pths = [pth for pth in Path(pt).iterdir() if pth.suffix == '.jpg']

for filename in asm_pths:
    (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(filename)
    print(str(filename) + "," + str(time.ctime(mtime)))
```

or

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import time

pt = r"K:\Folder"

for filename in Path(pt).iterdir():
    if filename.suffix == '.jpg':
        (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(filename)
        print(str(filename) + "," + str(time.ctime(mtime)))
```

You mixed two different methods

Comment: the solution with os.walk is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As you can tell I am still learning python. I would really appreciate if you could help me understand why the code worked for local directories. Thank you.

Comment: it can't run correctly for local folder. But if you don't have subfolders then it may display less filenames and some of them may have correct values and it may looks like it works correctly.